# How to disable marker's TITLE click event?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've seen how to disable marker click event but I have no clue on how to disable marker **TITLE** click event. If I disable marker click event, the title still remains clickable. How to disable it after the first click?

This is what I have tried:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(marker -> {
    //What to do?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code

```
Marker lastOpenned = null;

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // Check if there is an open info window
    if (lastOpenned != null) {
        // Close the info window
        lastOpenned.hideInfoWindow();

        // Is the marker the same marker that was already open
        if (lastOpenned.equals(marker)) {
            // Nullify the lastOpenned object
            lastOpenned = null;
            // Return so that the info window isn't openned again
            return true;
        } 
    }

    // Open the info window for the marker
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    // Re-assign the last openned such that we can close it later
    lastOpenned = marker;

    // Event was handled by our code do not launch default behaviour.
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: This what I have specified in my question, if disable click even on the marker, the title still remains clickable.

Comment: can you show me that piece of code by editing your question?

Comment: I don't use any cluster manager. I have a Map that has only one marker. The title is open and after exactly one click on the title, I want to remove the click event. The marker should not be clickable anymore.

Comment: Let me try and get you back.